# ggplot error: Found object is not a stat

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Africa_set$Africa_Predict, y = Africa_set$Africa_Real), color ="red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = Africa_set$Africa_Predict, y = predict(simplelm, newdata = Africa_set)),color="blue") +
  labs(title = "Africa Population",fill="") +
  xlab("Africa_set$Africa_Predict") + 
  ylab("Africa_set$Africa_Real")
```

Then show the error message:

```
Error: Found object is not a stat
```

How can fix this error?

Comment: When asking for help, be sure to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code. But you really shouldn't be using `$` within `aes()` calls, you should be passing in a `data=` parameter and using proper column names. And maybe look at `geom_smooth` if you want to plot a regression line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to plot points with a fitted regression line on top. You can do this using:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Or, if you really do want to use the model you've stored ahead of time in a `simplelm` object like you have in your example, you could use `augment` from the broom package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)

simplelm <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)


ggplot(data = augment(simplelm),
         aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(Petal.Length, .fitted), color = "blue")
```

Comment: error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval. any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? You shouldn't get anything like that with the examples I gave.